# Model mapper mapping Map<String,Object> to class which extends another generic class not working for list field

Tags: modelmapper

I am trying to create my custom configuration object from Map using model mapper. Everything gets mapped properly excepts the `fields` property which is coming fro Generic super class.

My target object is

```
public class ADParserConfig extends CustomParserConfig<ADParserConfigField> {

private String pattern;

public String getPattern() {
    return pattern;
}

public void setPattern(String pattern) {
    this.pattern = pattern;
}
```

}

This extends generic class CustomParserConfig

```
public class CustomParserConfig<T extends CustomParserConfigField> {

protected List<T> fields;
protected String timeStampField;

public List<T> getFields() {
    return fields;
}

public void setFields(List<T> fields) {
    this.fields = fields;
}

public String getTimeStampField() {
    return timeStampField;
}

public void setTimeStampField(String timeStampField) {
    this.timeStampField = timeStampField;
}
}
```

Where CustomParserConfigField is

```
public class CustomParserConfigField {

protected String name;
protected Integer index;
protected String type;
protected String format;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getIndex() {
    return index;
}

public void setIndex(Integer index) {
    this.index = index;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getFormat() {
    return format;
}

public void setFormat(String format) {
    this.format = format;
}
}
```

I am trying to map Map  using below function

```
ADParserConfig adParserConfig = getConfig(map,ADParserConfig.class);

 public  <T extends CustomParserConfig> T getConfig(Map<String,Object> configObject, Class<T> classType){
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    return modelMapper.map(configObject,classType);

}
```

Everything excepts `fields` gets mapped properly for the below map.

```
{fields=[{name=timeStamp, type=timestamp, format=dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS a}, {name=logName, type=string}], pattern=(?<timeStamp>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s[AMPMampm]{2})?\s(LogName=(?<logName>[\w\s\W]+))?\sSourceName=(?<sourceName>[\w\s\W]+)\sEventCode=(?<eventCode>[0-9]*), timeStampField=timestamp}
```

Please help. Why is issue happens only for fields object ? Do I need to specify something else in mapper configurations ?

Comment: Hi, it's a bug and I will fix it in https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/370.

Comment: Thanks Chun Han Hasio. Is there a work around for the same ? Can I achieve this using custom mapper ?

Comment: Maybe you can try https://gist.github.com/chhsiao90/b777d0468852837bac8060d5c4d7f81a .

Comment: I tried above workaround and it is not working. Gets me below error.
`org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Failed to instantiate instance of destination java.util.List. Ensure that java.util.List has a non-private no-argument constructor.`

Comment: 1) I have added stack trace [here](https://gist.github.com/chhsiao90/b777d0468852837bac8060d5c4d7f81a) as comment. Too long to add stack overflow comment.
2) I am using version - 2.1.0

Comment: I just checked with the latest version of modelmapper with the fix you have added. It works like a charm ! Thanks. Could you please add it as an answer so that I can marked as solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug and it had been fixed by [#370](https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/issues/370)

Comment: The work around has the issue which I mentioned as in questions comment. Could you please check this and try to solve , So that I can accept this answer ? #370 works like a charm! But not the work around.

Comment: You are right, I'm trying modelmapper latest stable build and the workaround didn't work. I will remove this workaround and try to figure out if there is any other workaround that we can apply.

Comment: Hi Chun Han : Any idea this fix will be released to maven repo ? Right now I am doing local maven repo build.

Comment: I just release modelmapper v2.1.1.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot Chun Han Hsiao. Model mapper is just awesome.